# toggle device toolbar (chrome) unexpectedly changing body width on html page

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Having an issue in which the body (and thus the rest of the containers on the page) are working fine on the responsive / fullscreen monitor mode, but when I toggle the device toolbar to see what it looks like on mobile, there is a noticable section to the right which i have no idea what/how/why it is there. Upon inspecting element it points to the html element but i have the width set to 100% and tried 100vw but nothing seems to work.

[image: what i expect]

[image: what happens when i toggle to mobile]

I am guessing it has something to do with the way %'s and vw's behave on mobile or possibly the way width works but am stumped and any help would be appreciated

EDIT: Reproducible code for the error (removed most other sections but the problem applies to all of them if i add it back

HTMLFILE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

    <link rel="manifest" href="favicon_io (1)/" />

    <title>David Chin Personal Website</title>
  </head>

  <!-- Header Section-->
  <body>
    <section class="header">
      <div class="header-container">
        <div class="col-1">
          <h2 class="expand">Dev</h2>
          <h2 class="expand">Chin</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
          <img src="assets/img/test.png" alt="test" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS FILE:

```
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 10px solid red;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: "Roboto Mono", monospace;
  border: 10px solid blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: pink;
}

.section-intro {
  margin-left: 10%;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 90vh;
  width: 100%;
  animation: 0.5 header ease 1.25s;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .header {
    display: flex;
  }
}

.header-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.header-container .col-1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 50%;
  animation: fadein 0.8s linear forwards;
}

.header-container .col-2 img {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: 0.5s fadein ease 1.25s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.header-container h2 {
  margin-block-start: 0;
  margin-block-end: 0;
}
.header-container .col-2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.header-container .expand {
  color: black;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 15rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 1ch;
  animation: 0.5s expand ease-in-out;
  animation-delay: 1.25s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transform: translateX(50vw);
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 6px grey;
}

/* Short term fix on text overflow */
@keyframes expand {
  0% {
    width: 1ch;
    font-size: 15rem;
  }
  80% {
    min-width: 330px;
  }
  100% {
    font-size: 7rem;
    transform: translateX(20vw) translateY(8rem);
    min-width: 330px;
  }
}
.header-container .img {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 3rem;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  opacity: 0;
  animation: 1s fadein linear;
  animation-delay: 1.25s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  max-width: 375px;
  max-height: 375px;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: add your code here also plz

Comment: There is something definitely wrong with my header css, as I just tried taking out only the header and the rest of the website is working perfectly fine

Comment: sorry for late try my solution down and let me know if it works .

Comment: @AymanMorsy Sorry for late reply - I ended up taking out the 2 columns from my header and using 1 column instead for my website. Also I tried your solution and it didnt work :(

Comment: so can you update the code , and another question I can't see the bottom of your screen in phone simulator , did you notice any horizontal scroll bar ?